# Why the JUnit is calling "object" and not "exception"?

Tags: java, exception, junit

I tried to write an exception class, and here is my code:

```
public class DealWithMeException {
   public DealWithMeException(String message){
      message="To make a class a checked exception it needs be a subclass of the appropriate Java class";
   }
}
```

When I run my JUnit test, the error always comes up and says **"calling Java.long.object instead of Java.long.exceptions"**

and here is my JUnit test code:

```
public class ExceptionsTest {
  @Test
  public final void testCheckedException() {
    Class<DealWithMeException> cut = DealWithMeException.class;
    assertEquals("To make a class a checked exception it needs be a subclass of the appropriate Java class",
                 Exception.class, cut.getSuperclass());
  }
}
```

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the exception class incorrectly.  An exception class must `extend` an existing exception class; e.g. `Exception` or `RuntimeException`.  (The technical requirement is that an exception class must be a subclass of `java.lang.Throwable`, but it is a really bad idea to extend that class directly.)

Your declaration doesn't explicitly extend anything.  That means that it implicitly extends `Object`.  In other words, it is *not* a valid exception class.  The fact that you have given the class a name that ends with `...Exception` is *immaterial*.

In short, the JUnit test is telling the truth.